# How to automatically run a Windows 8 program when a specific normal user logs on?

Tags: windows-8.1, uac, privileges, autostart

I have a desktop PC with **Windows 8.1 64-bit** installed. In order to share it with my roommate, I created a **normal user account** for him, and have installed some games and software, so that when I'm not using my computer, he is able to use them with the user account I've given to him.

However, the problem is that, his favourite game (LOL) **requires administrator privilege to start**, but I don't want to give the administrator password to him or disable UAC due to **security reasons**. So every time he wants to play this game, he needs to wait for me to come back and enter the password, which is very inconvenient.

Then I searched on Google whether there exists a way to play the game without administrator privilege, but it seems impossible to do so. Then I considered it would be good if the program can start **with administrator privilege** every time he **logs on**. Could anyone tell me whether it is possible to achieve this? Or any other way that my roommate can play this game without administrator privilege? Thank you very much.

Ps: I don't want the program to be started as a service, as it would be very annoying, and will slow down the boot up.

Comment: This trick for windows 7 may work in windows 8. I have not tried it. [how-create-program-shortcut-run-without-uac-prompt-windows](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-create-program-shortcut-run-without-uac-prompt-windows-7.htm)

Comment: It also works in Windows 8, and it's a good answer. Thank you very much. However, my problem is still not solved, as during the game, it still prompts administration password.

Comment: That sounds as though the scheduled task is not being used to directly run the program asking for privileges. Remember you do not run the program directly any more, the scheduled task actually runs the program. I have used the technique successfully on windows 7.

Comment: I agree with you. The program seems to be running like this: it first starts a log in manager, which requires admin privilege; after logging in, it calls another program, which also requires admin privilege. Now I've created a task to start the log in manager, and the program doesn't prompt password when it starts. However, after the submitting logging on information, it prompts password again.

Comment: These specifically mention windows 8. another link with things to try: [create-elevated-shortcut-run-programs-bypass-uac](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-elevated-shortcut-run-programs-bypass-uac). And another one: [http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/193743-elevated-program-shortcut-create-standard-user.html](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/193743-elevated-program-shortcut-create-standard-user.html).